# IDW Interpolation of point rainfall data using Python

Tags: python, boundary, spatial-interpolation

I am trying to plot the interpolation maps in Python for the point rainfall data. I have given the shapefile of the study area as my extent boundary for the interpolation, however, the code only gives me the interpolated map as a fixed rectangle with my shapefile boundary enclosed.
How can I modify the code such that it uses the provided shapefile as the boundary extent only as we usually draw in ArcMap?

[Plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmbTI.png)

Following code was used to plot the interpolation maps:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# Function to calculate IDW interpolation
def idw_interpolation(obs_points, values, new_points, power=2):
    tree = cKDTree(obs_points)
    distances, indices = tree.query(new_points, k=3)
    weights = 1.0 / distances**power
    weights /= weights.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    interpolated_values = np.sum(weights * values[indices], axis=1)
    return interpolated_values

# Read gauge data from Excel file
gauge_data = pd.read_excel('gauge_data.xlsx')

# Read shapefile of the study area
study_area = gpd.read_file('MountainousRegion.shp')

# Calculate extent of the shapefile
min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = study_area.total_bounds

# Generate grid points within the study area
num_points = 100  # Number of grid points in each dimension
x = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, num_points)
y = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, num_points)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
grid_points = np.column_stack((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()))

# Rainfall columns to interpolate
rainfall_columns = ['Gauge', 'Rainfall1', 'Rainfall2']

# Create subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(rainfall_columns), figsize=(7.5, 4.5))

# Collect maximum rainfall value from all columns
max_rainfall = gauge_data[rainfall_columns].max().max()

for i, rainfall_col in enumerate(rainfall_columns):
    # Perform IDW interpolation for current rainfall column
    interpolated_values = idw_interpolation(gauge_data[['Longitude', 'Latitude']].values, gauge_data[rainfall_col].values, grid_points)
    interpolated_grid = interpolated_values.reshape(xx.shape)
    
    # Plot interpolated rainfall within the extent of the shapefile
    im = axes[i].imshow(interpolated_grid, extent=[min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y], origin='lower', cmap='jet', aspect='auto', vmax=max_rainfall)
    
    # Plot shapefile
    study_area.plot(ax=axes[i], facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
    
    # Set title and axis labels with Times New Roman font
    axes[i].set_title(f'{rainfall_col}', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=12)
    axes[i].set_xlabel('Longitude', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=12)
    axes[i].set_ylabel('Latitude', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=12)

# Adjust space between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

# Plot colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(axes[-1])
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="9%", pad=0.2)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
cbar.set_label('Rainfall (mm/day)', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=12)

# Save the figure in high resolution (300 DPI)
plt.savefig('interpolation_maps.png', dpi=300)

# Show plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have tried the following command to limit the extent to my study area shapefile only, but it doesn't work:

```
 min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = study_area.total_bounds
```

Output of the interpolated map in rectangular boundary instead of shapefile boundary